# Using multiple structures of the same type within a union

Tags: c, unions

Currently, I have a structure that holds a list of booleans of the same type, for example:

```
typedef unsigned char U8
typedef struct
{
  U8  A1
  U8  A2
  U8  A3
  U8  B1
  U8  B2
  U8  B3
} NewStruct;
```

I am attempting to use a union to split these members into Group A and Group B (since the groups actually contain 100+ variables) so one can call for Group A or Group B and save some memory in the process:

```
typedef unsigned char U8
typedef union
{
    typedef struct
    {
      U8  A1
      U8  A2
      U8  A3
    } NewStruct_1;

    typedef struct
    {
      U8  B1
      U8  B2
      U8  B3
    } NewStruct_2;
} NewUnion;
```

I'm a bit new to C and I have not dealt much with unions. I'm wondering if this would be an adequate/helpful way to address the situation.

Thank you

Comment: This will work, however keep in mind, you'll need some other state to keep track of whether you have group A or B in the union.

Comment: It also means that you will have to change all of the code that accesses the NewStruct members.  Before, you would access `x.A1`, with the union, you'd access `x.NewStruct_1.A1`, for a variable named x.

Comment: The code you wrote so far defines two types inside the union, and no members

Answer (score 1):

It is not unreasonable to use a union of two similar structures. (One could not say it is good in your particular situation without more information.)

The correct syntax is:

```
typedef unsigned char U8;
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        U8  A1;
        U8  A2;
        U8  A3;
    } NewStruct_1;

    struct
    {
        U8  B1;
        U8  B2;
        U8  B3;
    } NewStruct_2;
} NewUnion;
```

Additionally, removing the names from the internal structure members makes them anonymous, and then the `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `B1`, `B2`, and `B3` members appear as if they were members of the outer union:

```
typedef unsigned char U8;
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        U8  A1;
        U8  A2;
        U8  A3;
    };

    struct
    {
        U8  B1;
        U8  B2;
        U8  B3;
    };
} NewUnion;
```

Then, if `x` is a `NewUnion`, you can use `x.A1` rather than `x.NewStruct_1.A1`.

Comment: Hey Eric - Thank you for your response. Using anon structures will be particularly helpful. What are the drawbacks of using my current method (as you alluded to in your first paragraph)? I'm currently using Python scripts to pull together variable names from Excel and generate these structures. Basically, this seems to be the "quick fix" at the moment.

Comment: @NickThomas: We just have next to no information about the needs of your project. I suppose your intent to split the members into Group A and Group B implies that A and B are partitions (any instance of the structure will, at any one point in time, hold only members from A or only members from B, never some from one and some from the other), that this partitioning is complete (there cannot be groups A, B, and C such that an instance holds only members from A or only members from B or only members from C), that you will always know which group an instance currently holds members from, etc.